# Top 10 results on rows obtained by UNION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, union

I am using MSSQL 2005 for a query, say:

```
SELECT * from Emp UNION ALL SELECT * from Emp2;
```

And I want to limit the final result to 10 rows.
IF I had only the Emp table, I would say

```
SELECT TOP 10 * from Emp;
```

But since I have 2 tables now, I can't say SELECT TOP * on any of them, neither I can use LIMIT 10 in the end.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: What does TOP mean without an ORDER BY?

Comment: it was not the real query, just an example.

Comment: it still may be relevant to explain (even in a fictional example) which TOP 10 you want.

Comment: Top without Order by means you'll just take any 10 records you can get.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM
(SELECT * from Emp UNION ALL SELECT * from Emp2) a
```

However, I would suggest maybe you order the results so that you don't just get top 10 results from first union result. So something like this maybe:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM
(SELECT * from Emp UNION ALL SELECT * from Emp2) a
ORDER BY a.lastName
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT top 10 * from (
    SELECT * from Emp UNION ALL SELECT * from Emp2) a
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * 
FROM  (
         SELECT * 
         FROM Emp 
          UNION ALL 
         SELECT * 
         FROM Emp2
      ) derivedTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the UNIONed query a subquery, and SELECT the TOP 10 rows from that:

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Emp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM Emp2
) unioned
```